# file upload not working codeigniter and no error showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have declared `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

my input type

```
    <textarea class="input-style" name="blog2" placeholder="Para 2"></textarea>
```

`<input type="file" name="blog_img" size="chars" class="upload-file" />`

my controller:

```
function upload()
{
    //set preferences
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|pdf';
    $config['max_size']    = '100';

    //load upload class library
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
    {
        // case - failure
        $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_file_view', $upload_error);
    }
    else
    {
        // case - success
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . $upload_data['file_name'] . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>';
        $this->load->view('upload_file_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello your form  have setup this enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> some this may issue

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it might be a file upload size issue.
You have to check your PHP configurations on php.ini file. If your upload is constantly being interrupted you either need to increase the maximum upload size or the time before your PHP script times out. Check this variables:

post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
max_execution_time
You can either increase in your PHP configuration file or increase in your script using the ini_set function. Check the manual for more details. PHP Manual

Answer (score 0):

input type='file' needs to be named 'userfile' by default

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

You can change the default to yours at 
$this->upload->do_upload('filename')
change this to 
$this->upload->do_upload('your file input name')

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
```

but in your file input name is `blog_img`, so us that instead of `filename`

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('blog_img'))
```